# How to send a binary file to a Lisp process with a pipe?

Tags: common-lisp

I need to send a binary file to a Lisp process as a pipe like that:

```
cat file.dat | my-program
```

The problem comes from the fact that the `*standard-input*` is a character stream:

```
(stream-element-type *standard-input*) 
=> CHARACTER
```

I know I can use named pipes instead, but this is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: some implementations can read binary data from such streams, too.